# I tried installing pip3 using the command prompt in windows but I got these error messages

Tags: python, django, windows, installation, pip

Hi everyone I am new to Python programming, I tried installing pip3 on my windows computer, I typed (pip3 install pipenv) on the command prompt but I got these error messages (Error message 1: ”`could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pipenv` (from versions: none”)
(Error message 2: no matching distribution found for pipenv)
Thank you.

Comment: whitch version of mython you are using

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What's your *Python* version? What about `pip3 install pipenv==2021.11.9`?